# Electron, how to make 100% sure renderer recieves message from main?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, google-chrome, electron

When sending messages from main electron(backend) to renderer(browser) with `ipcMain.send("plz_recieve", "hello")`, i noticed that if the browser window is not in view, like if you minimize or have it in the background it will actually miss that message from main/backend and will never be recieved.

```
    ipcRenderer.once("start_long_thingies_is_done_results", (e, renderVars) => {
        "WOHOOO"; 
        //if the browser window was in background or not in "focus" this message would never trigger
    });
```

So is there a way to 100% make sure that the renderer always recieves the message, and incase it's in the background/inactive/or whatever weird stuff is happening when not in focus, to then check if there was any missed messages?

Currently i have done a very ugly "hackish" way to accomplish this, but i feel like there's gotta be a proper way to send messages(the renderer have it's beautiful ipcrenderer.sendsync which works awesome to ensure recieved, but sadly main process only have ipcMain.send())

```
ipcRenderer.send("start_long_thingies"); //long random process for electron to execute
var timerId = setInterval(() => {
    ipcRenderer.send("are_we_done"); //ask every 200 ms if it's done
    //even if the window would ever become inactive/background, 
    //it would start asking again once you open the window, which makes this work
}, 200);
ipcRenderer.on("are_we_done_response", (e, state) => {
    if (state == true) { //is done then remove the timer asking if it's done
        clearInterval(timerId);
        ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners("are_we_done_response");
    }
});
```

--edit--
The above code is not 100% true, since the strings i used "are_we_done" are a simplification and not the original code :O

From the main process i do

```
ipcMain
    .on("start_long_thingies", (event: IpcMainEvent) => {
        state_running = true;
        //start very long process
        openssl.Entry_EncryptPath(s).then(() => {
           state_running = false;
        })
    })
//allow renderer to send if done or not
ipcMain.on("xxxx_is_done", (event: Electron.IpcMainEvent) => {
    event.sender.send("xxxx_is_done", state_running);
})
```

Comment: ipcMain does not have a `send()` function. Did you mean `webcontents.send`? It would be really helpful, if you could add the code of the main process too.

Comment: If you trigger the long process from the renderer process. `ipcRenderer.invoke()` may be your very best friend here. If you need to send it from the main, we need to look deeper into the issue - so a complete example that we can reproduce would be priceless here.

Comment: it's suspicious that minimizing the window prevents the message from being delivered. That's not what I would expect

Comment: @Rhayene Invoke sounds very intresting! will have to read and check what it is!

Comment: @pushkin yes, this is why I asked for a complete example - this may be a bug we have to report

Comment: @CoderBulletStorm would you mind sharing which electron version you use?